# Remove the grub menu after removing Windows dual boot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have a Spectre x360 laptop, one which I had dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed online to remove Windows, which was a success. However, the options to boot Ubuntu or Windows still remained when I booted up.

I have seen online that I can type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to remove obsolete entries from the starting up menu. I did this, but Windows boot option still appeared.

Next I added:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

to the:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

file. This removed the Windows option, but I still got that opening menu, allowing me to choose between:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced Options for Ubuntu
- System Settings

I just want to machine to boot up straight to Ubuntu.

How can I do this please?

Comment: askubuntu.com is more appropriate forum for this question. Although I have answered it below. HTH.

Comment: try this one, it worked for me ...!
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Answer (score 0):

You may use Boot Repair tool.

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

I found it to be very effective tool.

Comment: If my past experience is any indication, Boot-Repair will probably remove `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER` and makes Windows reappear again. As long as the computer gives the impression of having a legitimate Windows installation, this cannot be helped.

Comment: It worked for me when I had the similar issue.

Comment: Good to know. Still, knowing what makes the menu appear and what makes it disappear is very valuable.

Comment: I followed the instructions of Boot-Repair, but now I have around 10 options on the grub menu!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `os-prober` is still finding Windows is because those entries are still there in the ESP (EFI System Partition).

A very simple solution is to just delete the aforementioned entries. If you can't mount the EFI partition in your running system in order to edit there's always the option to do it from a live session.

Just delete any "Microsoft" and/or "Windows" folders/EFI files. Then, boot Ubuntu as usual and run `sudo update-grub` again. Windows is now gone for good.